How to handle table names with dots (".") in SQL Server using TypeORM in a NestJS application?
I'm working on a NestJS project where I need to interact with a SQL Server database. One of the tables in the database has a name with dots, specifically dbo.Bonos.Bonos. I'm using TypeORM to manage the database interactions, and I'm encountering issues when trying to query this table.
When I attempt to perform any operations on the table dbo.Bonos.Bonos using TypeORM, I get the following error:

Error: Invalid object name 'dbo.Bonos.Bonos '."

It seems that TypeORM has trouble handling table names with dots. Here is how I have defined my entity:
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity({ schema: 'dbo', name: 'Bonos.Bonos' }) // **** IMPORTANT: Define the table and schema name ****
export class BonosEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  idBono: number;

  @Column()
  codigo: string;

  @Column()
  promocionId: string;

  @Column()
  NIF: string;

  @Column()
  CUPS: string;

  @Column()
  habilitado: number;

  @Column({ type: 'date' })
  fechaInicio: Date;

  @Column({ type: 'date' })
  fechaFin: Date;

  @Column({ type: 'date' })
  fechaUso: Date;

  @Column()
  importe: number;
}



I assume that neither ANSI delimiter identifiers (double quotes (")), nor T-SQL delimiter identifiers (brackets ([])) worked when you tried those?

Though, in truth, using a period (.) character in an object name is a poor idea; avoid names that need to be delimit identified.

Looks like a bug in the "ORM", and i use the term loosely, it means it doesn't properly quote table names

I have tried using both ANSI delimiter identifiers (double quotes) and T-SQL delimiter identifiers (brackets), but I am still encountering issues.
When using double quotes, I receive the following error:
Error: An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.

Then I agree with @siggemannen . Like I stated before, such names are a bad idea. Some language don't support such names. Honestly, the better solution here is to actually rename your object.

You can try tracing the calls the orm makes to see what sql it generates. I guess as a workaround you can create a synonym that just forwards to the table

Thank you for your suggestions. Here are the steps I have taken based on your comment:
enabled query logging in my TypeORM configuration:
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { DataSourceConfig } from './config/data.source';
import { BonosModule } from './bonos/bonos.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: `.${process.env.NODE_ENV}.env`,
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      ...DataSourceConfig,
      logging: true, // Enable query logging
    }),
    BonosModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}

I created a synonym in SQL Server that acts as an alias for the table dbo.Bonos.Bonos:
CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[BonosBonos] FOR [dbo].[Bonos.Bonos];

I then updated my entity to use this synonym:
@Entity({ schema: 'dbo', name: 'BonosBonos' })

After making these changes, it worked!!
I want to thank both users who suggested these solutions.
